# Samba Share Configured by Ansible Not Accessible

Tags: samba, ansible

I am attempting to administer to Samba Shares' on a `Ubuntu 20.04` running `Samba 4.13.17-Ubuntu`.

I have an Ansible playbook that writes my Samba config to `smb.conf`

[image: ansible-samba]

and I am adding `writable` & `browseable` as `yes`

When I review the file in `smb.conf`

I see:

[image: smb.confg]

The `yes` has been changed to `True` (which doesn't jive with way I've seen most `smb.conf` examples (always using yes/no strings)

When I attempt to access the share, however I get that I am restricted from browsing the files.

[image: browse to share]

When I manually edit the file `smb.conf` on the server change the `True` to `yes`, and restart the service, everything works fine?

[image: updated smb.conf]
[image: updated browser]

I am running `ansible: stable 5.3.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gotta love Ansible.

**Short Answer:** wrap your `yes` and `no` values in `"` to have the values passed as strings.

**Longer Answer:** Ansible will treat a couple of keywords as a boolean when recorded plainly:

| Things Classified as a Boolean True | Things Classified as a Boolean False |
| --- | --- |
| Any number greater than zero | Any number less than or equal to zero |
| A Boolean value of `true` (case insensitive) | A Boolean value of `false` (case insensitive) |
| An Ansible-specific `Yes` (case insensitive) | An Ansible-specific `No` (case insensitive) |

So, as `Yes` and `No` values are Ansible-specific keywords, you will want to wrap them in quotes to make them a string. This is also true if you are working with values such as `"true"` and `"false"`.

Comment: Great! Thank you that worked!